# Cambiar el puerto de un WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webservice, visual-studio-2017

Buenos días,

He programado un WebService en C# con Visual Studio 2017 y funciona perfectamente. El problema es que una vez implantado en el servidor de producción IIS queda a la escucha en el puerto 80, y me piden que pase a escuchar en el puerto 8282.

¿ Me podéis decir se puede configurar ese cambio de puerto ?.

Gracias.

Comment: Y porque quieres cambiar el puerto del proyecto para debug?

Comment: Gracias por responder @Einer. No, quisiera cambiarlo en producción. El Cliente que lo va a consumir se empeña en que lo necesita ubicado en el puerto 8282 :-(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cambiar el puerto sigue las instrucciones:

1. Abrir IIS (Internet Information Services)
2. Da clic derecho a tu sitio y selecciona la opción **`Modificar enlaces`**
3. Selecciona el protocolo a modificar, por ejemplo, `http` o `https`, luego da clic en el botón **`Modificar`**
4. En la caja de texto del `Puerto`, selecciona `8282`
5. Da clic en el botón **`Aceptar`** y listo.

Comment: Gracias, estaba convencido que se debía cambiar en el proyecto Visual Studio. Mañana por la mañana lo voy a probar.

Comment: @MarcGuillot independientemente del ambiente, si se encuentra publicado en un IIS se deberá cambiar la configuración directamente ahí en el IIS ;)

Comment: Una consideración adicional es que probablemente tengas que agregar el puerto como Excepción en el Firewall de Windows. Esto porque no se trata de un puerto estándar http.

Comment: @JavierReséndiz totalmente de acuerdo, tanto el Firewall local del servidor como si llegaran a tener algún otro físico.